# Flask, I can't save the records into my txt file

Tags: python, flask, txt

I have a select tag which almost has 41 option and I want to save the records that were choosen by user into my text file as a list in Python.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

selected_diseases = []

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    global selected_diseases
    selected_diseases = request.form.getlist('disease')

    with open('selected_diseases.txt', 'w') as file:
        for disease in selected_diseases:
            file.write(disease + '\n')

    return "Saved! [symptoms: {}]".format(selected_diseases)

@app.route('/show_selected')
def show_selected():
    return "Choosen Symptoms: {}".format(selected_diseases)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

I'm trying to save the records that were choosen by user, Here is the idea:

**selected_diseases.txt**

[Fungal infection, Hepatitis C]
[Hepatitis E, Alcoholic hepatitis]

But the major problem is that I choose the records, clicking the submit button but can't be writed into my text file.

Answer (score -1):

Example Python

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

selected_diseases = []


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template(
        'index.html',
        data=[{'name': 'dis1'}, {'name': 'dis2'}, {'name': 'dis3'}])


@app.route("/test", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    global selected_diseases
    selected_diseases = request.form.getlist('comp_select')
    print(selected_diseases)
    with open('selected_diseases.txt', 'w') as file:
        for disease in selected_diseases:
            file.write(disease + '\n')
    return (str(selected_diseases))  # just to see what select is


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Example index.html:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('test') }}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Please select</span>
            <select name="comp_select" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple>
                {% for o in data %}
                <option value="{{ o.name }}">{{ o.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

selected_diseases.txt if you select the two first from index.html:
dis1
dis2

Working result
https://github.com/spawnmarvel/test/blob/main/selected.jpg

Comment: Please explain why this example was down voted? I just helped a man out.